# PowerShell RSS Feed Encoding (UTF-8 | ISO-8859-1) problematic

Tags: powershell, encoding, rss

I'm trying to download and parse a `rss feed` via `PowerShell`.

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://example.com/rss.php' -OutFile $file -UseBasicParsing -Headers @{"Content-Type"="text/html"; "charset"="utf-8"}`

Below you can see the response/download with a wrong encoding.

- `<description>Foo Ã¼bermitteln</description>` should be `Foo übermitteln`
- `<description>Gr&ouml;&#223;e<br></description>` should be `Größe`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0"> 
    <channel> 
        <title>Foo RSS-Feed</title> 
        <link>https://example.com</link> 
        <description>Foo Ã¼bermitteln</description> 
        <language>de-de</language> 
        <copyright>Copyright 2019 Example.com</copyright> 

        <item> 
            <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
            <link>https://example.com/details.php?id=1234&amp;hit=1</link> 
            <guid>1234</guid> 
            <category>Foo</category> 
            <pubDate>2019-08-09 10:12:49</pubDate> 
            <description>Gr&ouml;&#223;e<br></description>
        </item> 
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Anyone can give me a hint how I can successfully encode/decode the response and parse it into a `xml`?

---

Actually I manual encode the stream with the following code:

```
$rssResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Get -Headers $defaultHeaders -Uri $uri
$rss = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($rssResponse.RawContentStream.ToArray())
```

Response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0"> 
    <channel> 
        <title>Foo RSS-Feed</title> 
        <link>https://example.com</link> 
        <description>Foo übermitteln</description> 
        <language>de-de</language> 
        <copyright>Copyright 2019 Example.com</copyright> 

        <item> 
            <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
            <link>https://example.com/details.php?id=1234&amp;hit=1</link> 
            <guid>1234</guid> 
            <category>Foo</category> 
            <pubDate>2019-08-09 10:12:49</pubDate> 
            <description>Gr&ouml;&#223;e<br></description>
        </item> 
    </channel>
</rss>
```

But there is still something wrong..

Comment: What happens if you do `@{"Content-Type"="text/html"; "charset"=" ISO-8859-1"` ?

Comment: Same result. Doesn't matter if I change the charset. I have added some more infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an easier way, but given that your updated code gives you almost the wanted results, you only need to convert the HTML entities to normal text.

This should do that:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$rssResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Get -Headers $defaultHeaders -Uri $uri
$rss = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($rssResponse.RawContentStream.ToArray()))
```

Output:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0"> 
>     <channel> 
>         <title>Foo RSS-Feed</title> 
>         <link>https://example.com</link> 
>         <description>Foo übermitteln</description> 
>         <language>de-de</language> 
>         <copyright>Copyright 2019 Example.com</copyright> 
>
>         <item> 
>             <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
>             <link>https://example.com/details.php?id=1234&hit=1</link> 
>             <guid>1234</guid> 
>             <category>Foo</category> 
>             <pubDate>2019-08-09 10:12:49</pubDate> 
>             <description>Größe<br></description>
>         </item> 
>     </channel>
> </rss>
> ```